# dificuldade em fazer vogais ficarem maiusculas

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estava a fazer uma script e o objetivo dela era fazer com que os caracteres andem uma posição para a frente.

Porém eram só os caracteres alfabéticos e que andavam uma posição.
E por fim ela deveria transformar vogais minúsculas em maiúsculas.

Aqui esta o código:

```py
def LetterChanges(str):
    x = list(str)
    str = ''

    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] == 'z':
            str += 'A'
            continue

        # testa para ver se faz parte do alfabeto
        if x[i].isalpha():
            # faz a letra andar uma posição
            str += chr(ord(x[i]) + 1)
        else:
            str += x[i]

    # Faz as vogais ficarem grandes
    str.replace('e','E')
    str.replace('i','I')
    str.replace('o','O')
    str.replace('u','U')

    return str

print(LetterChanges(input()))
```

O código todo funciona a 100% apenas a parte das vogais é que não funciona.

Se alguém conseguir ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Para futuros visitantes, vale lembrar que você está sobrescrevendo a função global [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) dentro de sua função `LetterChanges`. Seria melhor escolher outro nome para o argumento da função para não conflitar com as funções embutidas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hugo, você precisa pegar o retorno do replace.

Você fez da seguinte forma:

```
str.replace('e','E')
```

Porém o replace retorna o valor alterado, portanto você precisa atribuir o retorno a uma variável:

```
str = str.replace('e','E')
```

Efetuando essa alteração, seu código funcionará como deseja